# Removing Node From Parent (Sprite Kit) Objective C

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am creating a side scrolling game with a node moving from right to left. The problem is when it goes off the screen it is not removing itself. The only way i can get it to work is by not calling my bat node method multiple times. but i need multiple bats coming onto the screen. The problem seems to be when i call my bat method more than once with either SKAction waitforDuration or performSelector afterDelay.

Bat Method

```
-(void) addBats
```

{
    int random = arc4random_uniform(self.size.height/2);

```
bats = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Bat1.png"];
bats.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:bats.texture size:bats.frame.size];
bats.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width * 9, random);
bats.zPosition = 4;
[bats setScale:0.3];
bats.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = enemyCategoryL4;
bats.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
bats.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategoryLevel4;
bats.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;

[L4foregroundNode addChild:bats];

SKAction *up = [SKAction moveByX:-1 y: -40 duration:1];
SKAction *down = [SKAction moveByX:-1 y:40 duration:1];
SKAction *action1 = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[up, down]]];

SKAction *action2 = [SKAction moveByX:-self.size.width * 10  y:0 duration:40.0];
SKAction *group = [SKAction group:@[action1, action2]];

[bats runAction:group];
```

}

-(void) update:(NSTimeInterval) currentTime
{

```
if(bats.position.x < -50)
{
    [bats removeFromParent]; 
    [self addBats];
}
```

}

The above only works if i call bats once every time. Is there a way i can call more than once and remove the bat each time one goes off screen?

Comment: Is `bats` defined as an iVar (of type `SKSpriteNode`) of a scene (just checking to get full picture)?

Comment: Yeah it's iVar of SKSpriteNode. do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: Okay, so you have pretty messy code here :) What you want is to create action sequence, or use completion handler as suggested. When action is finished, and that is when bats are off screen, you remove them from its parent...

Comment: Also, how do you know actually that old node is not removed from the scene if it is off screen (you can't see it)?

Comment: Oh, I see... If you are using `[SKAction waitForDuration];` to call `addBats`  after certain delay, then you loose a reference as user5556671 pointed. (still this means that nodes are not actually off screen as you said ;) because you can see them).

Comment: I've just tried your example out with a waitForDuration on it and it works beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example about how you can create a sprite, move it until it ends up off-screen and remove it right after that:

```
#import "GameScene.h"


@interface GameScene()

@property (nonatomic, strong)SKSpriteNode *sprite;

@end

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view{

    self.sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor purpleColor] size:CGSizeMake(50.0f,50.0f)];

    //Place a sprite on right edge of the screen (I assume that your view and a scene have same size)
    self.sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height / 2.0f);

    SKAction *moveSprite = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(-self.sprite.size.width, self.frame.size.height / 2.0f) duration:5.0f];

    SKAction *removeSprite = [SKAction removeFromParent];

    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveSprite, removeSprite]];

    [self addChild:self.sprite];

    [self.sprite runAction:sequence withKey:@"moving"];
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if (self.sprite.parent) {
        NSLog(@"Sprite has a parent");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Sprite doesn't have a parent");
    }
}

@end
```

Try this code with, and without `[SKAction removeFromParent]` (see what is printed after sprite is off screen in both cases).

Answer (score 1):

For each bat you create in addBats you can use runAction:completion: to run your scrolling action and then in the completion block remove the node from parent. The problem is probably that when you add multiple nodes you are losing reference to the one you want to remove.

This code should do what you want (untested):

```
SKAction *up = [SKAction moveByX:-1 y:-40 duration:1]; 
SKAction *down = [SKAction moveByX:-1 y:40 duration:1];
SKAction *action1 = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[up, down]]];
[bats runAction:action1];

SKAction *scroll = [SKAction moveByX:-self.size.width * 10 y:0 duration:40.0];
[bats runAction:scroll completion:^{
   [bats removeFromParent];
}];
```